# Writing unit-tests for PostgreSQL functions in PL/Python - is it possible/reasonable?

Tags: postgresql, unit-testing, plpgsql, plpython

I've found interesting PL/PGSQL framework for unit-testing of  PL/PGSQL procedures, called [pgTAP](http://pgtap.org/). But PostgreSQL supports another language for stored procedures - Python, which already has unit-testing framework in standard library and assert statement. What if write unit-tests for PGSQL procedures in PL/Python?

Is it possible? Is it good idea?

Comment: @MatheusOl I meant [PL/Python](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpython.html)

Comment: There is just too many possible answers depending on too many unknown circumstances, which makes it not a good fit for this site.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Can you at least specify that circumstances?